# How do I really enable events in Word VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, templates, events

I've found the instructions to enable events, but this does not always work. When I create a new document from a template events are not enabled.

I've got the **class module** to have word run with events including also a `documentbeforesave sub`, another module to instantiate, and `document_open` and `document_new` subs in `thisdocument`. However, when I create a new document from the template after starting Word, events are not enabled.

Also, when saving the document, events are still off. How do I turn them on automatically when starting a new document from the template or opening an existing document based on the template?

Comment: When you create a new file from template, are the macros still in the new document VBA?

Comment: The answer may be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5332378/420156) on StackOverflow, try it.